# Is there a license that prohibits code share and using outside the company?

Tags: licensing

I'm working on a tool for small development teams. And I want to sell them full source code of my application so that they'll be able to update/modify the app according to their needs.

Is there any existing license that I can use that prohibits:

- Tool usage outside the company
- Code sharing and publishing
- Creating own products based on my tool, publishing and selling them

And allows:

- Modify the existing code as much as they want
- Use the [modified] tool inside the company

?

Comment: You need to consult an attorney on this one.

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://apps.americanbar.org/buslaw/blt/2003-07-08/bullock.html) will help you familiarize the vocabulary needed to understand the surrounding licensing issue. As everyone says, please talk to a lawyer. Good luck.

Comment: You should consider making your software free software, and accept & welcome external contributions (which are making free software so valuable).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i think he considered it, and dismissied it as not economical. Not to dis Open Source, but it doesn't fit most businesses

Answer (score 6):

There are no standard (open-source) licenses that fit your needs.
Your requirement that your customers can't redistribute the software rules out all open-source licenses.

You can create your own license that allows the purchaser to make modifications for their own use but forbids redistribution. To create the license, you are well advised to consult a lawyer as copyright licenses are legal documents and writing such documents falls under the expertise of lawyers.